# Returning an JSON object from an API call using a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch

very basic question here (I'm a Javascript neophyte) that I oddly can't seem to find answered.  I'm having trouble storing and displaying the result of a function that uses a fetch call.  The code below spits out "undefined" in the console; any thoughts on what might be the problem?

```js
function getApi() {
  var obj;

  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => (obj = data));

  return obj;
}

let x = getApi();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: You are trying to output a value that hasn't been fetched yet. Fetch takes some time to make the call and send back the result, and it's asynchronous, meaning that when you console.log your value, getApi() didn't finish yet, therefore didn't set the obj

Comment: Two solutions to fix the problem, good old callback that runs inside `.then((data) => (obj = data));`, or the less old school async/await method 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Callback_function - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Answer (score 3):

The `fetch` method is asynchronous, so `obj` is undefined because your code is going to the next instruction without waiting the fetch. You can simply use `async/await` method that is a great way to make asynchronous calls because `await` will wait for the result before going to the next instruction.

```js
  

  async function getApi() {

      const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
        
      const obj = await response.json()
      
      return obj;
    }

(async() => {
   let x = await getApi();
   console.log(x);
})()
```